# how to re-write left join with multiple or conditions

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert data from staging tableA to target tableB after incremental logic. TableA is staging table and has new and updated records compared to target table. Update query is running fine but the insert is taking a lot of time to run, so trying to re-write the logic.

```
Select
    s.[column1],
    s.column2
FROM
    TableA S with (nolock) 
    LEFT JOIN TableB t with (nolock) ON
        (
            ISNULL(t.column1, -1) = ISNULL(s.column1, -1)
            AND
            ISNULL(t.[column2],-1) = ISNULL(s.[column2],-1)
        )
        OR
        (
            ISNULL(t.[column2],-1) = -1
            AND
            ISNULL(s.[column2],-1) <> -1
            AND
            ISNULL(t.[column1], -1) = ISNULL(s.column1, -1)
        )
        OR
        (
            ISNULL(t.[column1],-1) = -1
            AND
            ISNULL(s.[column1],-1) <> -1
            AND
            ISNULL(t.[column2], -1) = ISNULL(s.[column2], -1)
        ) 
WHERE
    t.column2 IS NULL
```

The current process is running for 3- 4 hours. I have added indexes for both columns on 2 tables, but it is not helping.
How to re-write the logic without using or in join condition.

Comment: `with (nolock)` <-- Don't do this.

Comment: _"but the insert is taking a lot of time to run"_ - **paste the plan**: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: why is your query absolutely littered with `ISNULL(s.column1, -1)` expressions? Using `ISNULL`  in a predicate will make your query non-SARGable, which means it will definitely contribute towards your query being slooow.

Comment: Does all this logic just reduce down to `If column1 or column2 equal eachother, then join`?

Comment: @JNevill It's worse than that... I've just re-formatted the query around the `AND`/`OR` combinators and I've no idea what's going on here...

Comment: Having a better understanding of your REAL data and the column context would help.  In the TableA (alias S), will column1 EVER be null? will column2 EVER be null? and if so, what is the purpose of what appears to be key components in a table join of ever being null to begin with.  sometimes by masking your project with generic column names and tables makes things harder to interpret purpose and alternative solutions.  What is is you are trying to merge together

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms you're using. The above code is product specific in several ways.

Comment: It may be worth looking at the new `IS DISTINCT FROM` comparison operator for performing nullable value comparisons. Usage: `value1 IS DISTINCT FROM value2` for inequality or `NOT value1 IS DISTINCT FROM value2` for equality. This will eliminate most of your `ISNULL()` function calls and allow SQL Server to use its indexes.  Some of your other tests can be replaced with simpler `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` tests.

Comment: @TN Why on earth did the ISO SQL committee decide to give _the most sought-after_ operator in SQL's history the _most unwieldly and excessively verbose syntax_? I swear they take joy in our suffering.

Comment: @Dai I agree wholeheartedly. I almost commented on that in my earlier post. I just realized that the syntax does allow the `value1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM value1` variant - better than the `NOT value1 IS DISTINCT FROM value2` syntax I posted earlier. Unfortunately. `IS DISTINCT FROM` does not look for exact matches. It still considers collation and (I think) ignores trailing spaces. You likely still need to cast as binary for exact matching.

Comment: @TN Or, y'know... they could have permitted  `!==` and `===`  instead? (for `IS DISTINCT FROM` and `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` respectively) - plus it'd be nice to see them acknowleding how 95% of SQL implementations allow `!=` as an alternative to `<>`.

Comment: https://thwack.solarwinds.com/groups/data-driven/b/blog/posts/bad-habits-putting-nolock-everywhere

Answer (score 0):

you can try using separate `LEFT JOIN` clauses for each condition and use `WHERE` clause to filter results.

```
LEFT JOIN TableB t1 with (nolock)
   ON ISNULL(t1.column1, -1) = ISNULL(s.column1, -1) AND 
   ISNULL(t1.column2, -1) = ISNULL(s.column2, -1)
LEFT JOIN TableB t2 with (nolock)
   ON ISNULL(t2.column1, -1) = ISNULL(s.column1, -1) AND 
   t2.column2 IS NULL
LEFT JOIN TableB t3 with (nolock)
   ON ISNULL(t3.column2, -1) = ISNULL(s.column2, -1) AND 
   t3.column1 IS NULL
WHERE t1.column1 IS NULL AND t2.column1 IS NULL AND t3.column2 IS NULL
```

Here the `WHERE` clause checks if all three `LEFT JOIN` conditions fail.

⚠️keep in mind that the performance is still depends on the size of the tables, and the indexing strategy. Ensure the appropriate indexes are still in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try rewritting using UNION ALL instead of OR condtion in LEFT JOIN as:

```
Select
s.[column1],
s.column2
FROM
TableA S 
LEFT JOIN TableB t 
    ON ISNULL(t.column1, -1) = ISNULL(s.column1, -1)
    AND ISNULL(t.[column2],-1) = ISNULL(s.[column2],-1)
WHERE
t.column2 IS NULL 
UNION ALL
Select
s.[column1],
s.column2
FROM
TableA S 
LEFT JOIN TableB t ON
    t.[column2] IS NULL -- ISNULL(t.[column2],-1) = -1
    AND s.[column2] IS NOT NULL -- ISNULL(s.[column2],-1) <> -1
    AND ISNULL(t.[column1], -1) = ISNULL(s.column1, -1)
    
WHERE
t.column2 IS NULL 
UNION ALL
Select
s.[column1],
s.column2
FROM
TableA S 
LEFT JOIN TableB t 
    ON  t.[column1] IS NULL -- ISNULL(t.[column1],-1) = -1
    AND s.[column1] IS NOT NULL -- ISNULL(s.[column1],-1) <> -1
    AND ISNULL(t.[column2], -1) = ISNULL(s.[column2], -1)
  
WHERE
t.column2 IS NULL
```

Comment: ...how is this an improvement, though?